# Calling tcl component from python script and back to tcl

Tags: python, tcl

I have a tool written in tcl which I would like to use with a Python script.
File1.tcl will call file2.py which will call procedure_a in file3.tcl.

File1.tcl

```
 set names(1) Jane
 set names(2) Tom
 set names(3) Elisabeth
 set names(4) Robert
 set names(5) Julia
 set names(6) Victoria

 set output [exec /home/Python-2.7.6/./python /home/usr1/tests/ file2.py   [array get names]]
```

file2.py

```
 from Tkinter import Tcl
 tcl = Tcl()
 tcl.eval('source /home/mbenabu/vtf/procs/Linux/file3.tcl')
 tcl.eval('proc1 {%s} ' % [sys.argv[1]])


file3.tcl
   proc proc1 (array)
      // do something with the array.
```

Question:
  When I’m calling proc1 from the py script, the ‘array’ received in proc1 is a string not an array thus the call to 'proc1’ from the py script fail.

How can I send  an array to proc1?

Answer (score 0):

Sending an array is tricky — in Tcl, they're collections of *variables* and not *values*, and that's a very important distinction because variables are not first-class entities — but you *can* send a serialization of an array and reconstruct it, which works fine for sending the values over.

To serialize an array, use `array get` which returns a *dictionary* value. Your code sample does this already. The reverse operation is `array set`, which goes inside the procedure being called:

```
proc proc1 {dictionary} {
    array set ary $dictionary
    # Now we have a copy of the array and can do what we want to it
    puts "ary(1) is $ary(1)"
}
```

If you were running inside the same Tcl interpreter, you'd have other alternatives like having a shared global array. Or you could use something like [Tequila](http://equi4.com/metakit/tequila.html) to create a shared array service, though there's a *lot* of caveats if you go that route (and I wouldn't personally do it).